# combine characters of 2 strings considering match and order python

Tags: python, list, loops, substitution

I have a fileA like:

```
s
q
s
s
e
```

and fileB:

```
*************m******************************m**m******************m********m
```

I have to substitute the "m" in fileB according with the list of fileA like:

```
*************s******************************q**s******************s********e
```

I did something but doesn't work:

```
    filea = open("filea.txt")
fileb = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open("fileb.txt")]
for tc in filea:
    dew = fileb[0]
    pus = -1
    while True:
        pus = dew.find('m', pus + 1)
        if pus == -1:
            dew.replace('m', tc)
```

Comment: What language is this question for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `iter` with `next`, combined with `re.sub`:

```
import re
vals = (i.strip('\n') for i in open('fileA.txt'))
result = re.sub('\w+', lambda _:next(vals), open('fileB.txt').read())
with open('fileB.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write(result)
```

Contents of `fileB.txt`:

```
*************s******************************q**s******************s********e'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that works, its just a quick solution.

```
with open("filea.txt", "r+") as write_file:
    line = write_file.readline()
    read_file = open("fileb.txt", "r")
    line2 = read_file.readlines()
    read_file.close()
    for ch in line2:
        ch = ch.replace('\n', '')
        line = line.replace('m', ch, 1)
write_file.seek(0)
write_file.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is solution.

```py
file_a = './filea.txt'
file_b = './fileb.txt'

with open(file_a, 'r') as f:
    list_a = [str(x).strip() for x in f.readlines()]

with open(file_b, 'r') as f:
    str_b = f.readline()

for c in list_a:
    str_b = str_b.replace("m", c, 1)

# print(str_b)
```

`replace (before, after)` replace  ALL  `before` strings to`after` it.
You should use `replace(before, after, times)`. You can specify how many times to replace using `times`.

The `tc` contains `\n`, so it needs `tc.strip()`.